# CPanel - Wildcard SSL - How to point *.example.com to one root and sub.example.com to another root

Tags: security-certificate, cpanel

I have a wildcard (`*.example.com`) SSL certificate installed on my CPanel server.  I have `example.com` configured to point to `/example.com` as its document root and use this wildcard SSL certificate.  I also have `sub.example.com` configured to point to `/sub.example.com` as its document root.  I have not explicitly configured configured `sub.example.com` to use the wildcard SSL certificate.

When I go to `http://sub.example.com` it goes to the correct document root, however my problem is that when I go to `https://sub.example.com` it goes to the incorrect root, it goes to the root configured for the wildcard SSL.  I've been trying to find information on how to go about configuring `sub.example.com` to use the SSL certificate and go to the correct document root, however, so far I haven't found anything concrete.  Do I use the same steps that I used for configuring the certificate for `example.com`, but use the same certificate again and specify `dev.example.com` as the domain that this certificate is for (instead of `*.example.com`)?  Or is there something else I should be doing?

This is a production server, so I don't want to play around too much.  I'm hoping to find the correct information before proceeding.

Answer (score 1):

It was a long time ago I worked with cPanel, but I will try to answer the best I can. If someone else has something to contribute to this post - feel free to edit.

According to a [blog post](http://www.gnode.net/subdomains-with-wildcard-ssl-certificates-in-cpanel/) OpenSSL prevents multiple SSL virtual hosts on a single IP address. You can either use mod_rewrite or follow a possible solution laid out in the blog post.